compilation problem after upgrading bootstrap and ng-bootstrap in angular v17
i have upgrade my bootstrap and ng-bootstrap in my angular v17 project. I have upgraded bootstrap to v5.2.3 from v4.5.3 and ng-bootstrap to v16.0.0 from v15.1.2, but after upgrading i am facing compilation problems.
below is the error i am facing:
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial chunk files                        | Names                   |  Raw size   
vendor.js                                  | vendor                  |   5.38 MB | 
main.js                                    | main                    |   4.10 MB | 
polyfills.js                               | polyfills               | 335.02 kB | 
styles.js                                  | styles                  | 243.39 kB | 
runtime.js                                 | runtime                 |  14.47 kB | 

                                           | Initial total           |  10.06 MB   

Lazy chunk files                           | Names                   |  Raw size   
node_modules_pdfmake_build_pdfmake_js.js   | pdfmake-build-pdfmake   |   2.94 MB | 
node_modules_pdfmake_build_vfs_fonts_js.js | pdfmake-build-vfs_fonts | 793.37 kB | 

Build at: 2024-05-13T11:42:40.762Z - Hash: 7b2eefad9110f9f0 - Time: 60213ms        

./src/styles/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined variable.
   ╷
21 │   @each $color, $value in $theme-colors-rgb {
   │                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  bootstrap\scss\_root.scss 21:27           @import
  src\styles\bootstrap\bootstrap.scss 13:9  @import
  src\styles\styles.scss 2:9                root stylesheet

./src/app/core/components/main/main.component.scss?ngResource - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined mixin.
    ╷
182 │ ┌       @include hover {
183 │ │         color: darken($app-footer-text-color, 15%);
184 │ └       }
    ╵
  src\app\core\components\main\main.component.scss 182:7  root stylesheet

./src/app/orders/components/subscriptions/subscriptions.component.scss?ngResource - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined mixin.
   ╷
51 │ ┌     @include hover {
52 │ │       background-color: $app-gray-000;
53 │ │       border-radius: 0;
54 │ └     }
   ╵
  src\app\orders\components\subscriptions\subscriptions.component.scss 51:5  root stylesheet

./src/app/profile/components/profile/profile.component.scss?ngResource - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined mixin.
   ╷
54 │ ┌     @include hover {
55 │ │       color: $app-gray-200;
56 │ └     }
   ╵
  src\app\profile\components\profile\profile.component.scss 54:5  root stylesheet

./src/styles/styles.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):    
Undefined variable.
   ╷
21 │   @each $color, $value in $theme-colors-rgb {
   │                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  bootstrap\scss\_root.scss 21:27           @import
  src\styles\bootstrap\bootstrap.scss 13:9  @import
  src\styles\styles.scss 2:9                root stylesheet

Error: src/app/orders/components/orders/orders.component.ts:3:10 - error TS2724: '"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"' has no exported member named 'NgbAccordion'. Did you mean 'NgbAccordionItem'?

3 import { NgbAccordion, NgbModal, NgbAccordionConfig, NgbAccordionModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/orders/components/subscriptions/subscriptions.component.ts:13:10 - error TS2724: '"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"' has 
no exported member named 'NgbAccordion'. Did you mean 'NgbAccordionItem'?

13 import { NgbAccordion, NgbModal, NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/products/components/np-filters/np-filters.component.ts:19:10 - error TS2724: '"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"' has no exported member named 'NgbAccordion'. Did you mean 'NgbAccordionItem'?

19 import { NgbAccordion, NgbAccordionConfig, NgbAccordionModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/support/components/faq-content/faq-content.component.ts:4:20 - error TS2724: '"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"' has no exported member named 'NgbAccordion'. Did you mean 'NgbAccordionItem'?

4 import { NgbModal, NgbAccordion } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~




** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


× Failed to compile.

below dependencise of package.json file:
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.3.6",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.6",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.6",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^15.0.0-beta.42",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.6",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.6",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.6",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^17.3.6",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts": "^1.0.9",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^16.0.0",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^17.2.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^17.2.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^17.2.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^17.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^17.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^17.2.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^3.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.1",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.1",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "jszip": ">=3.8.0",
    "loader-utils": ">=1.4.2",
    "minimatch": "^9.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^13.2.1",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-stripe": "^16.4.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.31",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^2.6.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.6",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^17.3.6",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^17.3.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.119",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.37",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "http-server": "^0.12.3",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.8",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "jshint": "^2.10.3",
    "jszip": ">=3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "loader-utils": ">=1.4.2",
    "minimatch": ">=3.0.5",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.4",
    "postcss-scss": "^4.0.6",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "5.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}

i did tried to solve the error by reading the documantion but i didn't help much.

Have you tried to delete the node_modules?  Try rm -rf node_modules/ npm install

@Winthorpe i did tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and then npm install. This did not worked.

Is it possible to update your question with the package.json file to show all the dependencies?

@Winthorpe i did updated the question, do check.

Remove the depreciated NgbAccordion import.  That's depreciated in Angular 17.  You are already importing the new correct import NgbAccordionModule.  The screenshot in your question shows it is imported three times.  Remove them all.

When updating to @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap version 16.0.0 remove all imports of depreciated NgbAccordion.
In other words remove
import { NgbAccordion } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

Replace it with:
import { NgbAccordionModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

From the official documentation page for the Accordion component, with the relevant part quoted below:

This page describes accordion directives that were introduced in
14.1.0. Previous implementation of the accordion was component-based and was removed in 16.0.0.
You can find documentation and examples for the old version here.


Hey @Winthorpe, thank you for the solution. It worked and the issue of NgbAccordion is solved

I'm glad it worked.  Good luck with future coding.  If it solved the answer you should mark it as the 'accepted answer' (the tick icon) . :)
